# How can I check the fields from an array result

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have an array response from API. I want to check all of the dates from array result if it is greater than {today's date} before proceeding to the else if condition.

Here's what I did

```js
Sample array result:
array = [
{
id = 1
name = Jerry
date = 2020-07-17
subject = Math
},
{
id = 2
name = Tom
date = 2015-07-17
subject = Science
},
{
id = 3
name = Lily
date = 2018-07-17
subject = Biology
}
]
```

```js
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
 
   if (new Date(array[i].dates) > today) {
     //do something
   
   }else if (new Date(array[i].dates) < today) {
     //do something
 }else{
     //do something
  }
 }
}
```

1. I notice that it is checking all the conditions. When the index becomes 1 it goes to if,elseif,else condition.
2. So I figured out that it is not the right way to check the all of the dates in an array before proceeding to the next condition which is the else if condition.
3. For example I have three result in my array and I want to check all of the dates from each index in the first condition and if it satisfy the condition then it will do its designated task in that condition.

Comment: As it is, your question is really unclear. Could you [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65149219/edit) to include an example Array, and the result you expect? Or maybe pseudo code?

Comment: In the first `if` you use `new Date(array[i].dates)`, which presumes an array of objects, each of which has a `dates` property. In your second `if` you use `new Date(array[i]).dates`, which attempts to parse the array element itself as a `Date`, then get a `dates` property off of the `Date`, which will fail, since `Date` objects do not (natively) have a `dates` property. Also `else` is a statement, not a function - no need for parentheses.

Comment: I made some typo error. I've already got an answer. Thank you man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to perform the check.

```js
let array = [{
    id : 1,
    name : 'Jerry',
    date : '2020 - 07 - 17',
    subject : 'Math'
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name : 'Tom',
    date : '2015 - 07 - 17',
    subject : 'Science'
  },
  {
    id : 3,
    name : 'Lily',
    date : '2018 - 07 - 17',
    subject : 'Biology'
  }
];
const today = new Date;
if(array.every(({date})=>new Date(date.replace(/\s+/g, '')) > today)){
  console.log('valid');
} else {
  console.log('invalid');
}
```

Comment: @MarieBiscuits No problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's some typos. Your code should be something like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const date = new Date(array[i].dates);
  if (date > today) {
    //do something
  } else if (date < today) {
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I made some typo, Thanks.